# alphanumeric shellcode

Tags: shellcode, metasploit

I have generated an alphanumeric shellcode with this command:

```
msfvenom -a x86 --platform linux -p linux/x86/exec CMD=/bin/sh -e x86/alpha_mixed BufferRegister=ECX -f python
```

I am targeting a 32 bits x86 architecture on Linux.

Here is the shell code (i've converted it into a string):

```
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII7QZjAXP0A0AkAAQ2AB2BB0BBABXP8ABuJI0jTK68mIcbCVrHDmsSOyywSXfO2SsXgpe86OSRSY2NOyYs1Byxc8s0WpUPDo0b2I2NVOCCSXs0V7RsK9yq8Mk0AA
```

Here is a very basic c program which runs the shellcode:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef void (*shellcode_t)();
// unsigned char code[] = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";
unsigned char code[] = "IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII7QZjAXP0A0AkAAQ2AB2BB0BBABXP8ABuJI0jTK68mIcbCVrHDmsSOyywSXfO2SsXgpe86OSRSY2NOyYs1Byxc8s0WpUPDo0b2I2NVOCCSXs0V7RsK9yq8Mk0AA";


int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  shellcode_t appel = (shellcode_t)code;
  appel();

  return 0;
}
```

Here is how i compile it:

```
$ cc -Wall -m32 -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -O0 test.c -o test
```

When i run the program i get a segfault.

Please note the classical shellcode i've commented in the c program works perfectly. So it is not a c program compilation issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure of your crafted alphanumeric shellcode ? Because, I tried to read it and it seems just non sense to me... Have you tried to understand this shellcode in-depth?

Comment: no in fact i want first to first get a working alphanumeric shellcode. And then i want to understand how it works. This is why i am testing it first

Comment: Well, as this one is obviously not working I think you should do the other way around. First understand and, then, make it work! :-)

Comment: My goal is to understand how it works but i need a sample first. What i am looking for is how make an int 80 instruction with only alpha numeric...

Comment: Read this [phrack article](http://phrack.org/issues/57/15.html). It explains everything in details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alphanumeric shellcode expects the location of the shellcode to be stored in a register, since the usual technique of call/pop can't be performed with the limited character set.

In your example above this is set using BufferRegister=ECX, your C program doesn't take this into account though, which is why it crashes. Taking out the BufferRegister directive will give you a shellcode blob that determines the location manually, but isn't pure alphanumeric. This should run in your program though.

An alternative would be to use something that runs shellcode from a file, since these often have a jmp/call reg32, which you can then use with BufferRegister.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me more about jmp/call i do not understand what it changes to be from a file

Comment: The `jmp`/`call` technique is just a technique used to find the address of the string whatever you are located in memory (it's a PIC method). The first `jmp` goes to the `call` which is just before the string `"/bin/sh"` and the `call` send the `eip` to the instruction just after the original `jmp`. Meanwhile, the `call` has pushed the return address on the stack, which is in fact the address of the string. This technique is fully documented on Internet in several articles.